# How to enter values to an array using a method that has random maker?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomArray {
    /**
     * Fills an array with random integers in the range from
     * zero to one less than the array size.
     *
     * @param array the array to fill with random integers
     */
    public static void fillArrayWithRandomInts(int array[]) {
        java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random(13);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
            array[i] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * array.length);
    }

    public static int countSlotsWithIndexEqualToValue(int array[]) {
        int value = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i == array[value]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void printArray(int array[]) {
        System.out.println(array);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the array size: ");
        int arraySize = in.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[arraySize];
        fillArrayWithRandomInts(array);
        countSlotsWithIndexEqualToValue(array);
        printArray(array);
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far. The main point to is to allow the user to enter an array size and then with that size send it to method `fillArrayWithRandomInts()` so it can randomly make the values.  Then with the second method, check to see if any of the random values equal the index of the array that it is in; for example `array[0] == 0` would be a match, with `array[0]` being the position of the array and `0` being the random value.

Comment: What does your code cause problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of bugs I see here:

- You're not actually counting the elements in your array; you're only checking to see if the first element in your array is equal to `i`.  What you'd want to do is check to see if the element as position `i` is equal to `i` instead:

  ```
  if(array[i] == i) {
      // logic
  }
  ```
- You're not doing anything with the return value in `main` - you let it fall flat on the ground.  You should store it in a variable somewhere:

  ```
  int equivalentElements = countSlotsWithIndexEqualToValue(array);
  ```

There's also a weird thing I'm noticing:  your method will (surprisingly) work to generate the random elements into the array, but there's a nicer way:  use [`Random#nextInt(int n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) instead to guarantee that you're in the bounds of your array, and that you'll always be getting back an `int`.

```
array[i] = random.nextInt(array.length);
```

The number in your `Random` constructor is a seed, so regardless of what you enter in as your size, you'll always be getting the same pattern of generation.  Bear that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RandomArray {    

    public static void fillArrayWithRandomInts(int array[]) {
        java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random(13);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
            array[i] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * array.length);

        }
    }    
    public static int countSlotsWithIndexEqualToValue(int array[]) {           
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i == array[i]) {
                count++;                }
        }
        return count;
    }    
    public static void printArray(int array[]) {
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the array size: ");
        int arraySize = in.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[arraySize];
        fillArrayWithRandomInts(array);
        int count=  countSlotsWithIndexEqualToValue(array);
        System.out.println("the count is "+count);
        printArray(array);
    }
}
```